# Saving rendered image into a file doesn't work

Tags: rendering

I've seen many videos on saving your work as an image, and it is told that pressing <kbd>F3</kbd> should do that.

However it does not work for me - when I press <kbd>F3</kbd> nothing comes up when a menu for saving is supposed to come up.

If it has to do with what computer I have I use, I have windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Do you hover your mouse cursor over UV / Image Editor (where your rendered image should be shown) before pressing `F3`? Beware that many keyboard shortcuts are different for different [editors](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/) hence you should make sure you use `F3` shortcut where it acts as you expect it. If that's not the case please elaborate on your problem with more info / screenshots of what exactly not working.

Comment: see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39042/1853 and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21409/my-saved-work-does-not-reopen/21418#21418

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually render your image first before you can save your render as a file. To do that press <kbd>F12</kbd> while your cursor is over your 3D View window.

Wait for the render to finish and only after that with the mouse cursor hovering the rendered image can you press <kbd>F3</kbd> to save it. Alternatively if the hotkey for some reason is not working you can save your render by going to the *Image Menu > Save Image As*, by default at the bottom of the *UV Image*  Window

Are you using a laptop computer by any chance? Some computers by default use the function keys <kbd>F1</kbd>  to <kbd>F12</kbd> as direct shortcut keys for Microsoft Office or other Microsoft applications, and to use them as regular F keys you have to press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button on your keyboard.