# Blender 2.83 F keys

Tags: shortcut

I have blender 2.83 and when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> it doesn't open the render view tell me there are no more keyframes to jump to in this direction. Also, <kbd>F1</kbd> puts the PC to sleep instead of bringing up a help menu. Sorry, noob to blender coming from Maya

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50010/saving-rendered-image-into-a-file-doesnt-work/50014#50014

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a laptop, you may need to disable its "Fn" key in the BIOS at bootup.